# GCP composer best suitable versions of providers

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

Where i can find best suitable version for any provider with resepct to the airflow version
for example Airflow version 2.2.5 best sutaible version of goolge provider is 4.0.0

Answer (score 0):

You can find all these informations in the official documentation : https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/versioning/composer-versions

For each Airflow version, you can see the different versions of the packages that are included.

Comment: It has the list of packages which are already installed in its docker i am talking about new packages which will be extrenally installed via UI in PYPI packages

Comment: Oh okay, i'm not sure this kind of detailed documentation exists. I think you will have to try by yourself.